# Can't override CSS rule

Tags: javascript, html, css, zepto

In my CSS, I have an element with the id of `#home`:

```css
body >#home, body[orient="portrait"] > #home{
    top:87px !important;
    background: white!important;
}
```

When I then close a popup-window a class gets added to that same element:

```css
body >.angularFtw, body[orient="portrait"] > .angularFtw{
    top:170px !important;
}
```

```
<ul id="home" class="angularFtw">
```

But when `.angularFtw` gets added it ignores the rules. All I want to do is to give that element another `top` position.

The project I am working with has a lot of hacks like `!important`. The library used is ZeptoJS and I can't add query etc.

Any ideas how to give that element another `top:x` styling with vanilla JS/CSS?

And I'm not sure if classes can override the rules of ids?

**Update**

My element starts out like this:

```
<ul id="home">
```

Then I try to give it a new position by adding a class:

```
<ul id="home" class="angularFtw">
```

And I am not allowed to change the CSS below:

```css
body >#home, body[orient="portrait"] > #home{
    top:87px !important;
    background: white!important;
}
```

So in order to give that element a new position I have to somehow add new rules. Using either some inline styling hack or JS.

They are using the CSS rules above for some other stuff. Thats why I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: Is .angularFtw the same element as #home? If it is, the ID property has a greater specificity than the class property so the first rule will override the second.

Comment: Note that an `#ID` selector has a higher specificity value than any other selectors in CSS. Not saying I recommend this, but if you wan't to fix the problem with the current selectors, you could try: `body[orient="portrait"] > #home.angularFtw`

Comment: Might be a specificity problem. Adding the identifier to your second set of selectors  should fix it ( or eliminating the id `#home` from the first ). Try to use a class `.home` or `.no-angularFtw` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a class to `#home` instead of using the id. That's because ids are stronger than classes.

Even if you add a selector with the same length but uses a class instead of the id, it will be ignored.

Or you can add the id `#home` to the selector:

```css
body >#home.angularFtw, body[orient="portrait"] > #home.angularFtw
```

This should work as well.